# How to wire a C-wire from a humidifier to a Carrier furnace?

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire, humidifier

I need guidance on a wire. One wire connects the humidistat to HUM. Another wire should go from the humidifier to COM24Vac. My COM is taken as you see in the picture. Is it an issue to wire the second wire to Y instead of COM?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You *may* be able to attach multiple wires to the `C` terminal, or you could use a pigtail as described [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/80264/33).

Connecting the wire to the `Y` terminal, will not work.